# How to integrate IDP-initiated SSO with AWS API gateway using Auth0?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, saml, auth0

I have a React App + Set of lambda's which are using JWT api gateway authorizer (using cognito user pool as IDP)

Additionally I have an Auth0 app + SAML IDP-initiated enterprise connection which direct the logged users in my React App along with SAML assertion.

What will be the best and simplest solution to enable users who are directed to the React app with the SAML to be authorized in the API gateway?

I have came up with this possible solution: create a custom API gateway authorizer which will accept the SAML assertion and will validate it using passport.

1. Is my solution applicable?
2. Is there an existing solution (code reference) for such authorizer? (could not find such...)
3. Are there simpler \ better solutions?